# Keep the same space between lines in OL3 despite scale

Tags: javascript, openlayers, cartography

I have 2 lines (in 1 layer - ol.layer.Vector) for 1 road (each line represents different direction). The problem is that when you zoom out then you see only 1 line because they "merge" together as they are so close to each other (cca 20 meters). Is it possible to style the layer in the same way as google traffic layer - so you could see both lines even in small scale?
Zoomed in:
[image: Zoomed in]

Zoomed out: 
[image: Zoomed out]
This is how it should look like (zoomed out):
[image: Google traffic]